# How to get the symmetric difference between two Streams in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given that I have two Java 8 Streams of the same type, how do I efficiently get the symmetric difference of these two as a new Stream?

Comment: Isn't symmetric difference for sets? I guess you'd have to translate those streams to sets first.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but I'm asking to see if there's a better way.

Comment: I don't see any. Streams 'stream' over some collection, so you can always only see one element at once. I don't think that streams fit the job. For doing set operations, use sets. If you have limited memory, you _could_ use streams, but you's have O(n^2) time complexity as you'd have to iterate the streams multiple times.

Comment: @tobias_k But you *can't* iterate streams more than once, right? They're like Iterators, not Iterables. Also, Streams don't 'stream' over some collection, necessarily. `Stream.iterate("a", s -> s.concat("a"))` gives an infinite stream that doesn't come from any collection.

Comment: @David Conrad: conceptionally, they are iterating over a collection, even when that collection doesn’t exist as a memory structure, like when defining it using `iterate`. And they may be infinite. That doesn’t make the task of the question easier…

Comment: @Holger No, conceptually, they are not iterating over a collection. They are only iterating over a collection when they are actually iterating over a collection, that extends `java.util.Collection`. A collection implies more than just a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an efficient way of doing it. The best I managed was

```
static <T> Stream<T> symmetricDifference(Stream<T> stream1, Stream<T> stream2) {
    Set<T> elements1 = stream1.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<T> elements2 = stream2.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>(elements1);
    result.addAll(elements2);
    elements1.retainAll(elements2);
    result.removeAll(elements1);
    return result.stream();
}
```

which is probably the solution you already came up with.

Even when trying to use stream operations to come up with the symmetric difference, I found myself having to produce lots of temporary streams and sets in order to get over the problem that I have to iterate over the streams multiple times. Here is a version that produces a  `Stream` containing the symmetric difference, using only stream operations. You can see that it is far more inefficient.

```
static <T> Stream<T> disjointStream(Stream<T> stream1, Stream<T> stream2) {
    Set<T> elements1 = stream1.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<T> elements2 = stream2.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<T> elementsIn1Notin2 = elements1.stream().filter(t -> !elements2.stream().anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(t))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<T> elementsIn2Notin1 = elements2.stream().filter(t -> !elements1.stream().anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(t))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return Stream.concat(elementsIn1Notin2.stream(), elementsIn2Notin1.stream());
}
```

I'm putting this up because I'd be interested to see how it can be improved while retaining only stream operations (no `Set` or `Collection` operations apart from `Collection.stream()`); and also how my clunky syntax can be improved.

*As an aside, for people who are just getting into Java 8 and wondering where these classes are, my imports are:*

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```